# Can someone identify this biplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

My grandfather in the back seat apparently.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

It is a British [Airco DH9A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A) light bomber.

**Some more info**: According to an RAF [database](http://www.rafweb.org/Members%20Pages/Aircraft%20Serials/Operational%20Units.htm), this particular aircraft with registration **E848** served in RAF No. 27 and No. 30 squadrons. Both of these squadrons flew sorties over India and the Middle East after World War I (hence the additional radiator fitted under the fuselage to operate in warmer climates, well spotted by Peter Kämpf), but I can't find anything more specific about E848 that would place it in either squadron in particular at any specific point in history.

Comment: Light is the word for it.

Comment: Minor detail: It has the additional radiator fitted under the fuselage to operate in the Middle East in the 1920s (in a particularly shameful episode of British warfare).

Comment: @PeterKämpf Wow, well spotted! You've motivated me to try to find out a bit more about the history of this particular aircraft ...

Comment: @PeterKämpf: Would that be the one where the RAF bombed the Kurds with mustard gas?